# How to pass variable from smarty to javascript in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I want to add variable into smarty and then read value in javascipt. In header.tpl I have:

```
function setVarHeaders() {
            varHeaders = 0;
            lang = "{$cart->id_lang}";
        }

        </script>
    </head>
```

And in my global.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('#HOOK_PAYMENT').each(function (index, element) {
        var html = '';

        html += '<div id="value">' + lang +'</div>';
        $(element).html(html);        
    }); 
});
```

Where is the problem ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from available code, you don't call `setVarHeaders` function, so variables are never set. You can call it where it defined:

```
        function setVarHeaders() {
            varHeaders = 0;
            lang = "{$cart->id_lang}";
        }

        setVarHeaders();

        </script>
    </head>
```

or where these variables used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    setVarHeaders();

    $('#HOOK_PAYMENT').each(function (index, element) {
        var html = '';

        html += '<div id="value">' + lang +'</div>';
        $(element).html(html);        
    }); 
});
```